# How to use alamofire post request swift 3 with Parameter and callback?

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I am using this function for alamofire request. Please suggest me what I am doing wrong?

```
func requestForLogin(Url:String,username: String,password: String, completion: @escaping (_ Dic: NSDictionary?,_ status:NSInteger) -> Void) {
    var dic=NSDictionary()


    let params: Parameters = [
        "user": username,
        "pass": password
    ]

    Alamofire.request(Url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print("Validation Successful")
                dic=(response.result.value) as! NSDictionary

                var error = NSInteger()
                error=dic.object(forKey: "error") as! NSInteger
                completion(dic,error)

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)

                completion(dic,0)

            }


    }
}
```

Comment: Your issue is? can you tell us?

Comment: I am not getting Response

Comment: you are getting failure as result?

Comment: Use native Swift types instead of `Foundation` types, such as `Int` instead of `NSInteger` and `Dictionary` instead of `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 2):

> **Using Almofire and SwiftyJSON you can easily call JSON Formate**

```
import Alamofire // pod 'Alamofire'
import SDWebImage // pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'

//remoteLogin JSON Parsing
func remoteLogin()
{
    let params : Parameters = [
        "user": "username",
        "pass": "password"
    ]
    
    print("param is \(params)")
    
    let url = URL(string: "\(Constant.API)login")!
    print("Url printed \(url)")
    
    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120
    
    manager.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params)
        .responseJSON
        {
            response in
            
            switch (response.result)
            {
            case .success:
                
                //do json stuff
                let jsonResponse = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
                print("JsonResponse printed \(jsonResponse)")
                
                //check authenticate is yes or no..
                let myInt: Bool = jsonResponse["authenticate"]! as! Bool
                
                if (myInt == true)
                {
                    //do Success stuff

                    //If you want to use Array then
                    //var data = NSArray()
                    //data = dicsResponse.value(forKey: "data") as! NSArray

                    //If you are using table then get the data array value like this
                    //let name = (data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "name") as? String
                    //print("GetNameData \(name)")

                    //If you want to use Image
                    //let url = URL.init(string:"\(companyLogo!)")
                    //Img_Logo!.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: ""), completed: nil)

                    
                    //alertview
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: Constants.APP_ALERT_TITLE, message: Constants.SUCCESS_MESSAGE, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
                }
                else
                {
                    //do Error stuff
                    
                    //alertview
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: Constants.APP_ALERT_TITLE, message: Constants.ERROR_MESSAGE, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
                }
                break
                
            case .failure(let error):
                
                if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                    //HANDLE TIMEOUT HERE
                }
                
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: Constants.APP_ALERT_TITLE, message: Constants.ERROR_MESSAGE, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
                
                print("\n\nAuth request failed with error:\n \(error)")
                break
            }
    }
}
```

OR Using Wrapper Class you can use easily call Almofire API.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2dvzr9rl6tt0ltt/HttpWrapperClass.zip?dl=0

> **Or if there is SHOP API using then here is code.**

```
let postString: NSMutableDictionary? = ["user_name":Txt_Login.text!,"password":Txt_Password.text!]
        
        let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString!, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(Constants.API)\(Constants.LOGIN)")!,
                                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        request.httpBody = json!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(){
                    AppDelegate.shared().HideHUD()
                }
            } else {
                AppDelegate.shared().HideHUD()
                let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                print("responseString = \(responseString!)")
                
                let Data = self.convertToDictionary(text: responseString!)
                print("Get Item \(Data!["data"]!)")
                
                let jsonResponse = Data!["data"]! as! NSArray
                
                let myInt: Bool = Data!["Success"]! as! Bool
                if (myInt == true)
                {
                   
                }
                else{
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                        AppDelegate.shared().HideHUD()
                        AppDelegate.shared().ShowAlert(title: Constants.ERROR_HEADER, msg: Data!["Message"] as! String)
                    }
                }
               
            }
        })
        
        dataTask.resume()
    }
    
    func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
        if let data = text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]
                print(json)
                return json
            } catch {
                print("Something went wrong")
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

> **If you getting this error "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection."**

You have to add just the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES in the NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your info.plist file.

For example,

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
```

**OR You can use Model-View-ViewModel**

> Use Alamofire with Model Data

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
```

> AppDelegate Methods

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
var window: UIWindow?

    //TODO: showHud
        func showHud(){
            SVProgressHUD.setDefaultStyle(.custom)
            SVProgressHUD.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.clear)
            SVProgressHUD.setBackgroundLayerColor(UIColor.clear)
            SVProgressHUD.setRingNoTextRadius(25.0)
            SVProgressHUD.show()
            
            if !UIApplication.shared.isIgnoringInteractionEvents {
                UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            }
        }
        
        //TODO: hideHud
        func hideHud(){
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            }
        }
```

> Add Function of Alamofire View Model Class

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SVProgressHUD

class UserViewModel{
    
    weak var vc: ViewController?
    var arrCategory : UserModel!
    
    func getAllUsreDataAF(){
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Accept": "application/json",
        ]
        
        appDelegate.showHud()
        Alamofire.request(WebURL.baseURL, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
           print(response)
            appDelegate.hideHud()
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                self.arrCategory = try? JSONDecoder().decode(UserModel.self, from: response.data!)
               
                if self.arrCategory.status == 200 {
                    
                    print(self.arrCategory.data![0].productName!)
                    //DispatchQueue.main.async{
                      //self.vc?.tblView.reloadData()
                    //}
                 }
            }else {
              
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

> ViewControllers Method

```
@IBOutlet weak var tbl_vw: UITableView!

var viewModelUser = UserViewModel()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    
    tbl_vw.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomeTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomeTableViewCell")
    viewModelUser.vc = self
    viewModelUser.getAllUsreDataAF()
}
```

**Create one UserModel class where you define your model using JsonExport or something else**

Answer (score 1):

check with printing your request body. You can print your request body with `debugprint` method.

Also you can check this request body with **Postman** google chrome addon. 
For cross checking only.

Try below code :-

```
let _request = Alamofire.request(Url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print("Validation Successful")
                    dic=(response.result.value) as! NSDictionary

                    var error = NSInteger()
                    error=dic.object(forKey: "error") as! NSInteger
                    completion(dic,error)

                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    completion(dic,0)
                }
        }
        debugPrint("whole _request ****",_request)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameter).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
              if let result = response.result.value {
                 print("Validation Successful")
                dic=(response.result.value) as! NSDictionary
                var error = NSInteger()
                error=dic.object(forKey: "error") as! NSInteger
                completion(dic,error)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                completion(dic,0)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the response because it is in JSON format. You will have to convert the JSON to Dictionary type.

To do so you can use the following code:

```
func convertToDictionary(_ string:String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

To use this in you code do this:

```
func requestForLogin(Url:String,username: String,password: String, completion: @escaping (_ Dic: [String:Any]?,_ status:Int) -> Void) {
    var dic:[String:Any]?

    let params: Parameters = [
        "user": username,
        "pass": password
    ]

    Alamofire.request(Url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print("Validation Successful")
                dic = convertToDictionary(response.result.value as? String ?? "") as? [String:Any]
                var error = Int()
                error = dic["error"] as? Int ?? 0
                completion(dic,error)

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)

                completion(dic,0)

            }
    }
}
```

Here I have used `[String:Any]` instead of `NSDictionary` and `Int` instead of `NSInteger`. Also you should not use force unwraps in a scenario like this. So I have changed that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Alamofire.request(URL + apiName, method: method, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        if let json: NSDictionary = response.result.value as? NSDictionary{
            print(json)

        }else {
            completion(nil, NSError.init(domain: ErrorMessage, code: 0, userInfo: nil))
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        print (error)
        completion(nil, NSError.init(domain: ErrorMessage, code: 0, userInfo: nil))
    }
```